# javascript for doesn't work in Internt Explorer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, for-loop

I wrote a script, that works perfectly in Chrome, Edge but not in IE.

the Script:

```
1 var higher = 1000000;
2 var lower = -1000000;
3 for (var [key, value] of stuetzen[selected].knicklaengen[val]) {
4     if (key >= inp && key < higher) {
5         higher = key;
6     } else if (key < inp && key > lower) {
7         lower = key;
8     }
9 }
```

The error seems to be in line 3.

knicklaengen is an array of maps. So im trying to run the for loop for every key once.

Brackets also tells me this:

```
ERROR:Parsing Error: Unexpected token [
```

Does anybody know how to fix this? And why only IE has a problem with this?

Thanks for Reading!

Comment: loop some other way. i mean... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of IE has no support for that.

Comment: You're trying to use EcmaScript-6 destructuring, which isn't supported in IE.

Comment: Either recode in the old fashioned way, or use Babel to transpile it.

Answer (score 0):

The `for ... of` loop is not supported in IE

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @Barmar there are two errors. One is about destructuring, (which is what the IE console is saying) and once this is solved there is still the problem of `for...of`. Having said that, the answer is incomplete, so it shouldn't be upvoted, IMHO.

Comment: To be fair, the solution is the same for both problems. Use a transpiler.